# Angular directive stops firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement an infinite scrolling directive. When the page first loads and it scrolls, I see the log on the console. However after the initial scroll, it doesn't happen anymore. It's like it only does it once.

Where am I going wrong?

Directive:

```
 directives.directive('ngScrolled', function() {
        return function(scope, elm, attr) {
            var raw = elm[0];

            elm.bind('scroll', function() {
                console.log('scroll direct');

                if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                    scope.$apply(attr.ngScrolled);
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

html:

```
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7" ng-style="resultsHolder" ng-include="'partials/resultCell.html'" ng-scrolled="loadMore()"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible the `div` is only actually being scrolled once and other scroll events are happening in higher level objects?  A fiddle would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NuclearGhost mentioned in a comment, it's probably that the scroll events are not firing on the element that you have the directive on.

Make sure you've got a wrapper/container element that has a height set with the proper overflow set.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6weX9/) with effectively your directive as written, and it works. It wouldn't work if the wrapper div didn't exist.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
    <div class="scroller" infinite-scroll="more()">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```